# Decrypt Synology PHP files

Tags: php, youtube, host, synology

I just downloaded a file of my Synology Diskstation but the content looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/eLLM8UZR

Is there a way to decrypt it?

The file is the youtube.php file for the Downloadstation.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first bytes of the file, it looks like it is a .bz2 (bzip) file. Popular "unzippers" like 7zip should be able to unzip it to a usable file. If you have a more recent Synology DS, you might even have a "bzip2" on the command line (check bzip2 --help how to work with this command).